# Permutation function in C#

Tags: c#, combinatorics, extension-methods

One thing lead to another and eventually I wanted to know the "proper" way of writing the permutation generating function in C#. Below is my code for generating permutations. This will go into an internal library, so the calling context is really generic. Expected calling is in a single-threaded context

```
/// <summary>
/// Generate all possible permutations of all elements in the list taken r at a time
/// Permutations: Choose 'r' letters from 'n' possible letters to form a word (sequence is important). 
/// Formula for counting: nPr = n! / (n - r)!
/// </summary>
/// <param name="list">The list whose permutations are needed</param>
/// <param name="startPos">The position of first element of interest in the list</param>
/// <param name="r">Number of items required in the permuted list</param>
/// <returns>An enumeration containing a permutation of the original list</returns>
public static IEnumerable<IList<T>> GetPermutations<T>(this IList<T> list, int r, int startPos = 0) {
    for (int i = startPos; i < list.Count; ++i) {
        if (r > 1) {
            list.Swap(startPos, i);
            foreach (var permute in GetPermutations(list, r - 1, startPos + 1))
                yield return new List<T>().AddRange(list[startPos].AsEnumerable(), permute);
            list.Swap(startPos, i);
        } else
            yield return new List<T>() { list[i] };
    }
}
```

The Utils class has the extensions used in the GetPermutations function

```
public static class Utils {
    public static bool Swap<T>(this IList<T> list, int i1, int i2) {
        if (i1 == i2)
            return false;
        var tmp = list[i1];
        list[i1] = list[i2];
        list[i2] = tmp;
        return true;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> AsEnumerable<T>(this T item) {
        yield return item;
    }

    public static List<T> AddRange<T>(this List<T> list, params IEnumerable<T>[] collections) {
        foreach (var collection in collections)
            list.AddRange(collection);
        return list;
    }

}
```

The code will be invoked as below

```
var items = new [] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
foreach (var permutation in items.GetPermutations(3))
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", permutation));
```

**Couple of things on which I would like to get feedback are:**

1. `yield return` in a recursive function.
2. Generation of new Lists to be `yield returned`, given that we will have a really large number of permutations with small increase in the input set

Comment: @mjolka Added the extension code. Also, changed name from `Yield` to `AsEnumerable`

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, you seem to be yielding a whole list, is this correct?

Comment: @RubberDuck Yes, If the caller calls with say a list of 5 items requesting permutations containing 5 items, then the function will yield return a list of 5 items

Comment: Okay. I think I understand now. It seemed odd to yield a list at first, but I see what you're doing now.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your (1) `yield return` in a recursive method ... Eric Lippert does it in [Producing Permutations series, Part Three](http://ericlippert.com/2013/04/22/producing-permutations-part-three/) , specifically in his `HamiltonianPermutationsIterator` recursive method.

I won't dive into your (2) only to suggest that perhaps you read all of Eric Lippert's series to learn more.

**Braces Need Improving**

On coding style, your use (or lack thereof) of braces could be improved.  The C# convention is to put the opening brace on a new line (this differs from Java).

More importantly is that you lack braces on so many one-liners.  This is heavily discouraged.

I would suggest cleaning your code to change a snippet from this:

```
if (r > 1) {
    list.Swap(startPos, i);
    foreach (var permute in GetPermutations(list, r - 1, startPos + 1))
        yield return new List<T>().AddRange(list[startPos].AsEnumerable(), permute);
    list.Swap(startPos, i);
} else
    yield return new List<T>() { list[i] };
```

To this:

```
if (r > 1) 
{
    list.Swap(startPos, i);
    foreach (var permute in GetPermutations(list, r - 1, startPos + 1))
    {
        yield return new List<T>().AddRange(list[startPos].AsEnumerable(), permute);
    }
    list.Swap(startPos, i);
} 
else
{
    yield return new List<T>() { list[i] };
}
```

**Swap Method**

You really don't do anything with the `bool` returned from the `Swap` method.  Plus I see little reasoning in not swapping 2 values that happen to be equal.  This method could simply be `void`.

You are also encouraged to have meaningful names in C#, so `i1` would be better named as `index1`.  Ditto for `i2`.

```
public static void Swap<T>(this IList<T> list, int index1, int index2) 
{
    var temp = list[index1];
    list[index1] = list[index2];
    list[index2] = temp;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rick. I will read the series by Eric. The `Swap` function is used by other methods. A stable sorting mechanism will need a sort with check. Returning a `bool` helps when doing count on `swap` versus `compare` in sorting and similar algorithms to determine their efficiency.

Comment: @Vikhram Since `Swap` has a firm meaning of strictly swapping for so many languages, perhaps `SwapIfDifferent` would be a more appropriate method name.

Comment: I would go for Swapify!

Comment: @dfhwze I'd go with [tuples](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/197599/59161) :-]