# BubbleSort - checking if bubblesort is decreasing the iterations through the array

Tags: c#, sorting

What I'm hoping my code is doing is instead of making 99 comparisons on every pass of a 100 element array, it will now make 98 comparisons on the second pass, 97 on the third pass and so on and thus decreasing the iteration through the array.

```
st.Reset();
st.Start();
double temp;
for (int pass = 1; pass < _arr.Length - 1; pass++)
{
    // Count how many times this next loop
    // becomes shorter and shorter
    for (int i = 0; i < _arr.Length - pass; i++)
    {
        if (_arr[i] > _arr[i + 1])
        {
            // Exchange elements
            temp = _arr[i];
            _arr[i] = _arr[i + 1];
            _arr[i + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
st.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("--Improvement 1--");
Program.printArray(_arr);//Display the contents after each iteration of the algorithm
Console.WriteLine("improvedBubbleSort 1 time taken to sort array: {0}", st.Elapsed);
```

Comment: You say you are 'hoping' that is the behavior. Have you stepped through in a debugger to see what it does?

Comment: You could also test for not exchange to stop

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Answer (score 1):

There are three things that come into my mind about improving your code.

- Use `CompareTo` instead of the *raw* `>` operator. This way you can sort any collection that contains `IComparable<T>` items.
- Use `ref var` to give the two values more meaningful names without copying them.
- Use tuples + `ref` to swap elements in a much nicer fashion without the need of the helper `temp` variable and without copying values.

Example:

```
public static void BubbleSort<T>(this T[] source) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    for (var pass = 1; pass < source.Length - 1; pass++)
    {
        for (var offset = 0; offset < source.Length - pass; offset++)
        {
            ref var current = ref source[offset];
            ref var next = ref source[offset + 1];

            if (current.CompareTo(next) > 0)
            {
                Swap(ref current, ref next);
            }
        }
    }

    // The new swap as local function
    void Swap(ref T x, ref T y) => (y, x) = (x, y); 
}
```

Comment: While I like the `ref var` local declaration and the Swap with tuples, I cannot upvote this since it does not have a mechanism to exit when it detects the list is sorted.

Comment: @RickDavin well, the other answer already mentioned that issue so I don't think it's necessary to repeat it.

Comment: zombie down :-p

Comment: @dfhwze haha, at the last minute because I was going to kill it myself with the _delete_ button ;-P

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed one loop
I think you can test for not swaps and break

Nice if you post a test harness

Minor changes.  I went int just for ease.

```
public static void BubbleSort(int[] arr)
{          
    if(arr.Length == 0)
    {
        arr = new int[100];
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = rnd.Next(arr.Length * 2);
            Debug.WriteLine(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    Debug.WriteLine("");
    Stopwatch st = new Stopwatch();
    st.Restart();
    int temp;
    bool clean = false;
    for (int pass = 1; pass < arr.Length; pass++)
    {
        clean = true;
        // Count how many times this next loop
        // becomes shorter and shorter
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - pass; i++)
        {
            //Debug.WriteLine($"i {i}   {i + 1}");
            if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1])
            {
                clean = false;
                // Exchange elements
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                arr[i + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
        if(clean)
        {
            break;
        }
        //Debug.WriteLine("");
    }
    st.Stop();
    Debug.WriteLine("--Improvement 1--");
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(arr[i]);
    }
    //Program.printArray(_arr);//Display the contents after each iteration of the algorithm
    Debug.WriteLine("improvedBubbleSort 1 time taken to sort array: {0}", st.Elapsed);
}
```